# Spring Boot AMQP @RabbitListener not receiving messages

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have a Spring Boot application, and I am trying to send and receive messages via RabbitMQ.

**Problem**

I can send the messages successfully to the queue (i.e. I see them on the queue in the RabbitMQ Manager), however my **Receiver** does not receive the messages.

I have a RESTful endpoint I call from JUnit that in turn calls the **Sender**. While this JUnit test is running the Spring context is loaded as expected, and the **Sender** is invoked that adds the messages to the queue successfully.

**Question**

Is there something more I need to do in order to get the **Receiver** to register so that it will listen for messages? (I suspect that because I am just running the JUnit test, it finishes before the **Receiver** can listen for messages).  Is there a way to keep the test up an running so that the **Receiver** can consume the messages before it ends?

**Code**

Sender

```
@Service
public class RabbitMQSender {

    @Autowired
    private AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Value("${rabbitmq.exchangename}")
    private String exchange;

    @Value("${rabbitmq.routingkeyname}")
    private String routingkey;  

    public void send(String uuid) {
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange, routingkey, uuid);
        System.out.println("Send RabbitMQ ("+exchange+" "+routingkey+")  msg = " + uuid);       
    }
}
```

Receiver

```
public class RabbitMQReceiver {

    @RabbitListener(queues = "${rabbitmq.queuename}")
    public void receive(String in) {
        System.out.println("Received RabbitMQ  msg = " + in);       
    }
}
```

Configuration

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfig {

    @Value("${rabbitmq.queuename}")
    String queueName;

    @Value("${rabbitmq.exchangename}")
    String exchange;

    @Value("${rabbitmq.routingkeyname}")
    String routingkey;

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(queueName, false);
    }

    @Bean
    DirectExchange exchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(exchange);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, DirectExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(routingkey);
    }

    @Profile("receiver")
    @Bean
    public RabbitMQReceiver receiver() {
        return new RabbitMQReceiver();
    }

    @Profile("sender")
    @Bean
    public RabbitMQSender sender() {
        return new RabbitMQSender();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your sender and receiver doesn't belong to the same profile ! did you run your Junit test with `@ActivesProfiles({"sender", "receiver"})` ?

Comment: @AbdelghaniRoussi - thank you!   That works now.

Comment: Welcome @Richard ! I will add a response to this Q, so that other people find the solution in the response section

Comment: Thanks, I will mark it as the answer, so that you get the points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sender and receiver doesn't belong to the same profile ! You should includes both profiles in your Junit tests using `@ActiveProfiles`

```
@ActivesProfiles({"sender", "receiver"})
```

Answer (score -2):

yuo need add @Component or @Service for  RabbitMQReceiver class

Comment: it works for me. thanks!